# how to pass a non json value to a angular.js http.post method?

Tags: javascript, php, http, angularjs, post

am trying to send two parameter in http post method in angular.js. i have done the following code

**controller**

```
var installerApp = angular.module('installerApp', []);
installerApp.controller('InstallerCntlr',function($scope,$http){
  $scope.getJson = function(param1,param2){
    console.log(param1) // working 
    console.log(param2); //working 
    $http.post('url',param1,param2).success(function(response){
      return response;
    });
  }
});
```

**my html**

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="installerApp">
   <div  ng-controller="InstallerCntlr">
      <div class="ins-ins-in-8" ng-click="hooks = getJson('1','2')" >
         {{ hooks }}
      </div>
   </div>
</html>
```

the param1,param2 value is seems null from the controles, i understand that controller get the value but it not sending via post method

can anyone please tell how we actually pass parameter in http.post method in angular js
thanks

**UPDATE** 
here is the solution for my prob
http://victorblog.com/2012/12/20/make-angularjs-http-service-behave-like-jquery-ajax/

Comment: Jason is not some guy, it's an acronym `JSON` or JavaScript Object Notation. "Jason" is funny tho...

Comment: can you please clarify about the problem.?

Comment: Not enough information in your request.  Need error messages.  Also, as above.  It's not "Jason," it's "JSON".  Also, you say, "The controller get the value" which tells me you are using MVC, and the controller is getting the value, so the parameters are successful.

Comment: that was just a spell mistake, actullay i was trying to send some params with angular post method

Comment: Try posting a demo to reproduce the issue. You can mock AJAX requests in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: i just want to send two params via post method in angular.js

Comment: $http.post('/someUrl', {a:'a',b:'b').success(successCallback);

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change this line.

```
$http.post('url',param1,param2).success(function(response){
```

To

```
data.param1 = param1;
data.param2 = param2;
$http.post('url',data).success(function(response){
```

That is if I've understood your question correctly.  If not, then please elaborate further and include a jsFiddle example.

Comment: after googling i understand that we only send params via content type change. either we need to change client side or server side. ref :  refer this http://victorblog.com/2012/12/20/make-angularjs-http-service-behave-like-jquery-ajax/